# How to change value of one element to key in array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I make value of one element into key in the same array
from this

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "segment"
    ["value"]=>
    string(9) "Name Test"
  }
```

to this

```
 ["segment"]=> "Name Test"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try and run each item through a function or foreach loop assigning it as you want.

```
$res = array();

foreach($data as $item) 
{
    $res[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
}
```

Or through a function such as array_walk

```
$res = array();

array_walk($data, function($item, $key) use (&$res) {
    $res[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying (if you have one row indexed as '0'):

```
$array = array('0' => array('name'=>'segment'
'value'=>'Name Test'));
$new_array = array();
$new_array[$array[0]['name']] = $array[0]['value'];
print_r($new_array);
```